# Validation of lookup fields

Tags: javascript, lookup-column, validation

I am using the following Javascript code using Script Editor on NewForm.aspx. It supposed to be working but by debugging I can see that the value returned from the dropdown select is empty. I looks to me that I am missing a .js library. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function PreSaveAction() 
{ 
   return formVal(); //calls the validation on save 
} 
function formVal() 
{ 
 if($("select[id^='Store #']:selected").text()=="<Select a store>") 
    {alert('Error:Please select valid store number from dropdown list before submitting'); 
    return false;
    } 
else { 
    alert(select[id^='Store #']:selected").text());
    return true;
     }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Well, are you missing a library, i.e. do you have `jquery.min.js` in where you are referencing it? Does the browser's console show any js load issues?

Comment: Thank you, Moe. Yes, I do. I actually ended up downloading jquery-3.3.1.min.js. Went to the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js, copied the content presented in the browser and pasted into a text file, changed the extension to .js and uploaded to SiteAssets. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The easiest way is to download the jquery.js, upload the file as is to your Site Assets and refer it from there. Copying the content directly to SP isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, Moe. I actually found an issue - my code was missing option before ":selected". It should say - $("select[id^='Store #'] option:selected.text()==<Select a store>"

Answer (score 0):

The psuedo selector ":selected" does not exist on the select element. It is located on the option element. So if you change it to the code below you should be getting a different result.

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function PreSaveAction() 
{ 
   return formVal(); //calls the validation on save 
} 
function formVal() 
{ 
 if($("option[id^='Store #']:selected").text()=="<Select a store>") 
    {alert('Error:Please select valid store number from dropdown list before submitting'); 
    return false;
    } 
else { 
    alert(option[id^='Store #']:selected").text());
    return true;
     }
} 
</script>
```

But you should have a look at those queryselectors. I dont think they are totally correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brannmar. Unfortunately, it did not help and it still comes back empty. I am very new to Javascript so please bear with me - might it be that I have not included the .js file properly. I went to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js and taken the content presented in the browser, pasted into a text file and changed the extension prior to loading into the SiteAssets. Am I doing it wrong? Also, can you please elaborate on what you mean by incorrect queryselectors